# Android монетизация приложений

Tags: android

Прошу подсказать, как можно осуществить монетизацию приложения под Android для физического лица (в смысле реально получить хоть какие-то деньги за свой труд).

Примечание: государство **Украина**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант - завести свой сервер, прицепить к нему базу данных покупателей и api для продажи контента. 
Далее делаете внутри приложения возможность покупки с вашего сервера. После покупки сохраняете на сервере идентификатор клиента(например гугло-аккаунт) и открываете полную версию.
Если вдруг пользователь удалит и заново установит ваше приложение, то ему надо будет лишь отправить запрос серверу на проверку и если он есть в базе, то заново открыть ему полную версию.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант!

Comment: вот только гугл не сильно приветствует такой вариант, а рекомендует использовать InApp Purchase.

Comment: В/на Украине не проходят платежи, поэтому я это и предложил. Конечно гугл не приветствует, ведь он 30 процентов с покупки берет себе :)

Comment: А если использовать такой вариант:
1. Приложение определить как бесплатное, разместить на своём сайте без Гугла (ведь это простой архив).
2. Вместо оплаты за скачивание попробовать вариант с добровольными пожертвованиями (например через карту Привата).
3. В этом случае не надо париться с лицензиями и т.д.

Как такой вариант?

Comment: пожертвования - это нормально. Но выкладывать на своем сайте инсталляцию - это плохое решение. Как минимум нужно будет изобретать обновление.

Comment: Почему в гугл плей нельзя такое приложение выложить?

Comment: @Deadkenny это уже другой вопрос. Но ответ в комментах есть. `вот только гугл не сильно приветствует такой вариант, а рекомендует использовать InApp Purchase` от KoVadim

Comment: И гугл заблокирует вас как нарушителя правил

Answer (score 0):

Знакомый привязал акаунт к киви карте и даже продает ─ Казахстан

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Answer (score 0):

Для монетизации рекомендую использовать

Appodeal ([http://appodeal.com](http://appodeal.com/+3aea6a08b4f6766c0707b31c83e48fbe)). Сам использую.

Преимущества Appodeal:

- Высокий CPM
- Автоматический отбор самой прибыльной рекламы со всех рекламных сетей
- Высокий Fillrate
- Минимальный порог для вывода средств 20$
- В любое время можно вывести средства

Вот ссылка на Appodeal - http://appodeal.com/+3aea6a08b4f6766c0707b31c83e48fbe

Answer (score 0):

Для монетизации android приложений рекомендую http://apperate.online/ 
Они сотрудничают с Яндекс, P&G и тп (более 50 рекламодателей)
+ предоплата за месяц) сразу, как внедряете  SDK